# Is it OK to store transactional primary key on data warehouse dimension table to relate between fact-dim?

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse

I have data source (postgres transactional system) like this (simplified, the actual tables has more fields than this) :
[image: ERD]

Then I need to create an ETL pipeline, where the required report is something like this :

- order number (from `sales_order_header`)
- item name (from `sales_order_lines`)
- batch shift start & end (from `receiving_batches`)
- delivered quantity, approved received quantity, rejected received quantity (from `receiving_inventories`)

My design for fact-dim tables is this (simplified).

[image]

What I don't know about, is the optimal ETL design.
Let's focus on how to insert the fact, and relationship between fact with `dim_sales_orders`

If I have staging tables like these:

[image]

The ETL runs daily. After 22:00, there will be no more receiving, so I can run the ETL at 23:00.
Then I can just fetch data from `sales_order_header` and `sales_order_lines`, so at 23:00, the script can runs, kind of :

```sql
INSERT
    INTO
    staging_sales_orders (
    SELECT
        order_number,
        item_name
    FROM
        sales_order_header soh,
        sales_order_lines sol
    WHERE
        soh.sales_order_id = sol.sales_order_header_id
        and date_trunc('day', sol.created_timestamp) = date_trunc('day', now())
    );
```

And for the fact table, can runs at 23:30, with query

```sql
SELECT
    soh.order_number,
    rb.batch_shift_start,
    rb.batch_shift_end,
    sol.item_name,
    ri.delivered_quantity,
    ri.approved_received_quantity,
    ri.rejected_received_quantity
FROM
    receiving_batches rb,
    receiving_inventories ri,
    sales_order_lines sol,
    sales_order_header soh
WHERE
    rb.batch_id = ri.batch_id
    AND ri.sales_order_line_id = sol.sales_order_line_id
    AND sol.sales_order_header_id = soh.sales_order_id
    AND date_trunc('day', sol.created_timestamp) = date_trunc('day', now())
```

But how to optimally load the data into fact table, particulary the fact table?

My approach

1. select from `staging_sales_orders` and insert them into `dim_sales_orders`, using auto increment primary key.
2. before inserting into `fact_receiving_inventories`, I need to know the `dim_sales_order_id`. So  in that case, I select :

```sql
SELECT
    dim_sales_order_id
FROM
    dim_sales_orders dso
WHERE
    order_number = staging_row.order_number
    AND item_name = staging_row.item_name
```

3. then insert to fact table.

Now what I doubt, is on point 2 (selecting from existing dim). In here, I select based on 2 varchar columns, which should be performance hit. Since in the normalized form, I'm thinking of modifying the staging tables, adding `sales_order_line_id` on both staging tables. Hence, during point 2 above, I can just do

```sql
SELECT
    dim_sales_order_id
FROM
    dim_sales_orders dso
WHERE
    sales_order_line_id = staging_row.sales_order_line_id
```

But as consequences, I will need to add `sales_order_line_id` into `dim_sales_orders`, which I don't find common on tutorials. I mean, adding transactional table PK, is technically can be done since I can access the data source. But is it a good DW fact-dim dimension, to add such transactional field (especially since it is PK)?
Or there is any other approach, rather than selecting the existing dim based on 2 varchars?

How to optimally select dimension id for fact tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is practically mandatory to include the source PK/BK in a dimension.

The standard process is to load your Dims and then load your facts. For the fact loads you translate the source data to the appropriate Dim SKs with lookups to the Dims using the PK/BK